# RUN Command for "View Update History" and "Installed Updates" Windows

Tags: windows-8.1

Is there any direct way to open the following control panel windows using a RUN command (or even a `cmd /c` command):
1. View Update History
2. Installed Updates
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try wmic qfe  
you can also specify a search by using wmic qfe | find "search string" this will just give you a list. Opening updates is a little different

Comment: A batch file will open it in a nicer format
 wmic qfe list full /format:htable > C:\WinUpdateList\updates.htm
start iexplore C:\WinUpdateList\updates.htm
Closest I can see to open the control panel is rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL appwiz.cpl